# When trying to fill a comboBox with list, get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have read every other question regarding this error (and there are many) and can't find anything related so here I am.  I am trying to fill the `dropdown` (`cmbEditProjType`) with the contents of the list I've created, then make it so that depending on which project number was picked, the text showing of `cmbEditProjType` will be that project's type. This gives them the ability to change if needed.

I get the above mentioned error pointing to my `comboBox`. I attempted to initialize it before adding the items to it, got the error; attempted to hard code one of the list items rather than pulling from the database, got the error. if you need any additional info please be nice and ask...

```
    Sub fillJobNoDropdown()

    cmbEditJobNo.Text = ""
    txtEditProjNo.Text = ""
    cmbEditProjNo.Text = ""
    txtEditProjName.Text = ""
    'cmbEditProjType.Items.Clear()  ERROR SHOWS HERE WHEN NOT CLEARED, ALSO TRIED = ""
    txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text = ""
    txtEditProjCost.Text = ""
    txtEditProjBudget.Text = ""

    'get values to populate Job No. dropdown with active projects
    Dim fillJobNo As New SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct JobNo from PT_Project WHERE Active = '1' and Deleted = '0'")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = fillJobNo.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            cmbEditJobNo.Items.Add(dr("JobNo))
        Else

        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

End Sub

Sub fillProjNoDropdown()

    cmbEditJobNo.Text = ""
    txtEditProjNo.Text = ""
    cmbEditProjNo.Text = ""
    txtEditProjName.Text = ""
    'cmbEditProjType.Text = ""   SAME THING: ERROR WHEN UNCOMMENT
    txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text = ""
    txtEditProjCost.Text = ""
    txtEditProjBudget.Text = ""

    Dim fillProjNo As New SqlCommand("SELECT ProjNo FROM PT_Project WHERE JobNo= '" & cmbEditJobNo.Text & "'")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = fillProjNo.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            If IsDBNull(dr("ProjNo")) Then
                cmbEditProjNo.Visible = False
                txtEditProjNo.Visible = True
                txtEditProjNo.Text = ""
                txtEditProjNo.Focus()
            Else
                cmbEditProjNo.Visible = True
                txtEditProjNo.Visible = False
                cmbEditProjNo.Items.Add(dr("RICC"))
            End If
        Else
            cmbEditProjNo.Visible = False
            txtEditProjNo.Visible = True
            txtEditProjNo.Text = ""
            txtEditProjNo.Focus()
            'if this happens and when saving will need to know if update or new
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub cmbEditJobNo_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbEditJobNo.GotFocus

    Call fillJobNoDropdown()

End Sub

Private Sub cmbEditJobNo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbEditJobNo.SelectedIndexChanged

    Call fillProjNoDropdown()

End Sub

Private Sub cmbEditProjNo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbEditProjNo.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim fillProjProjNo As New SqlCommand("SELECT ProjectName, ProjectType, ProjectTypeDescription, ProjectCost, ProjectBudgeted FROM PT_Project WHERE JobNo = '" & cmbEditJobNo.Text & "' AND ProjNo = '" & cmbEditProjNo.Text & "'")

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = fillProjProjNo.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            txtEditProjName.Text = dr("ProjectName")

            Dim valuesA As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            valuesA.Add("Home")
            valuesA.Add("Work")
            valuesA.Add("Maintain")
            valuesA.Add("Pool")
            valuesA.Add("Lawn")                

            'Filter distinct elements, and convert back into list
            Dim resultA As List(Of String) = valuesA.Distinct().ToList
            'Display result
            For Each elementA As String In resultA
                cmbEditProjType.Items.Add(elementA)
                cmbEditProjType.Text = dr("ProjectType")
            Next

            txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text = dr("ProjectTypeDescription")

            If IsDBNull(dr("ProjectCost")) Then
                txtEditProjCost.Text = 0.ToString("c")
            Else
                Dim formatProjCost As Decimal = dr("ProjectCost")
                txtEditProjCost.Text = formatProjCost.ToString("c")
            End If

            If IsDBNull(dr("ProjectBudgeted")) Then
                txtEditProjBudget.Text = 0.ToString("c")
            Else
                Dim formatProjBudg As Decimal = dr("ProjectBudgeted")
                txtEditProjBudget.Text = formatProjBudg.ToString("c")
            End If
            Exit Sub
            dr.Close()
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub txtEditProjNo_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtEditProjNo.GotFocus

    txtEditProjNo.ReadOnly = True
    Dim fillProj As New SqlCommand("SELECT ProjectName, ProjectType, ProjectTypeDescription, ProjectCost, ProjectBudgeted FROM PT_Project WHERE JobNo = '" & cmbEditJobNo.Text & "'")

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = fillProj.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            txtEditProjName.Text = dr("ProjectName")

            Dim valuesB As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            valuesB.Add("Home")
            valuesB.Add("Work")
            valuesB.Add("Pool")
            valuesB.Add("Maintain")
            valuesB.Add("Lawn")

            Dim resultB As List(Of String) = valuesB.Distinct().ToList
            For Each elementB As String In resultB
                cmbEditProjType.Items.Add(elementB)
                cmbEditProjType.Text = dr("ProjectType")
            Next

            txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text = dr("ProjectTypeDescription")

            If IsDBNull(dr("ProjectCost")) Then
                txtEditProjCost.Text = 0.ToString("c")
            Else
                Dim formatProjCost As Decimal = dr("ProjectCost")
                txtEditProjCost.Text = formatProjCost.ToString("c")
            End If

            If IsDBNull(dr("ProjectBudgeted")) Then
                txtEditProjBudget.Text = 0.ToString("c")
            Else
                Dim formatProjBudg As Decimal = dr("ProjectBudgeted")
                txtEditProjBudget.Text = formatProjBudg.ToString("c")
            End If
            Exit Sub
            dr.Close()
        Else
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

End Sub


Private Sub btnSaveProject_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveProject.Click

    Dim JobNo = cmbEditJObNo.Text
    Dim ProjNo = cmbEditProjNo.Text
    Dim ProjName = txtEditProjName.Text
    Dim ProjType = cmbEditProjType.Text
    Dim ProjTypeDesc = txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text
    Dim ProjCost = txtEditProjCost.Text
    Dim ProjBudg = txtEditProjBudget.Text

    'comfirm changes
    Dim Reply As String = ""

    If ProjName = "" Or ProjType = "" Then
        MsgBox("Project Name and Project Type are required to be filled in.")
    Else
        Reply = MsgBox("I am ready to SAVE / UPDATE Project " & JobNo & " / Project No. " & ProjNo & ". Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo)

        If Reply = vbYes Then
            'Update database based on changes made my user (from stored procedure)
            Dim dbUpdate As New SqlCommand("PT_AddManageProjects", frmMainMenu.DB)
            dbUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SPUse", 1))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JobNo", JobNo))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjNo", ProjNo))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectName", ProjName))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectType", ProjType))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectTypeDescription", ProjTypeDesc))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectCost", ProjCost))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectBudgeted", ProjBudg))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Deleted", DBNull.Value))
            dbUpdate.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Active", DBNull.Value))

            dbUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Project " & JobNo & " / Project No. " & ProjNo & " saved successfully.")
        Else
            'if no do nothing, go back to form
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtEditProjectName_LostFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtEditProjCost.LostFocus, txtEditProjBudget.LostFocus

    'validates that budget and cost are numeric values
    If txtEditProjBudget.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsNumeric(txtEditProjBudget.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a numeric Budget value")
        txtEditProjBudget.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtEditProjCost.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsNumeric(txtEditProjCost.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a numeric Cost value")
        txtEditProjCost.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteProject_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteProject.Click

    Dim JobNo = cmbEditJobNo.Text
    Dim ProjNo = cmbEditProjNo.Text
    Dim ProjName = txtEditProjName.Text
    Dim ProjType = cmbEditProjType.Text
    Dim ProjTypeDesc = txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text
    Dim ProjCost = txtEditProjCost.Text
    Dim ProjBudg = txtEditProjBudget.Text

    'check if changes have been made to any of the data first (compared to database)
    Dim compareProj As New SqlCommand("SELECT ProjectName, ProjectType, ProjectTypeDescription, ProjectCost, ProjectBudgeted FROM PT_Project WHERE JobNo = '" & JObNo & "' AND ProjNo = '" & ProjNo & "'", frmMainMenu.DB)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = compareProj.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            'if changes have been made, show error
            If ProjName <> dr("ProjectName") Or ProjType <> dr("ProjectType") Or ProjTypeDesc <> dr("ProjectTypeDescription") Then
                MsgBox("If you are attempting to delete a project, you cannot change any fields.  Please close this window and try again.  If needed, clear all fields and restart.")
                dr.Close()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

    'comfirm delete
    Dim Reply As String = ""

    If ProjName = "" Or ProjType = "" Then
        MsgBox("Project Name and Project Type required to be filled in.")
    Else
        Reply = MsgBox("I am ready to DELETE Project " & JobNo & " / Project No. " & ProjNo & ". Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo)
        If Reply = vbYes Then
            'if no changes, confirm delete, then change deleted to '1' and active to '0'
            Dim dbDelete As New SqlCommand("PT_AddManageProjects", frmMainMenu.DB)
            dbDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SPUse", 2))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JobNo", JobNo))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjNo", ProjNo))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectName", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectType", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectTypeDescription", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectCost", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectBudgeted", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Deleted", DBNull.Value))
            dbDelete.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Active", DBNull.Value))

            dbDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Project " & JobNo & " / Project No. " & ProjNo & " deleted succesfully.")
            cmbEditJobNo.Items.Clear()
            'call sub to clear fields and update jobno dropdown with only active non-deleted projects
            Call fillJobNoDropdown()
        Else
            'if no do nothing, go back to form
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub optAdd_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles optAdd.CheckedChanged

    If optAdd.Checked = True Then
        grpEdit.Visible = False
        grpAdd.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNewProject_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNewProject.Click

    Dim JobNo = txtAddJobNo.Text
    Dim ProjNo = txtAddProjNo.Text
    Dim ProjName = txtAddProjName.Text
    Dim ProjType = cmbAddProjType.Text
    Dim ProjTypeDesc = txtAddProjTypeDesc.Text
    Dim ProjCost = txtAddProjCost.Text
    Dim ProjBudg = txtAddProjBudget.Text

    Dim readProj As New SqlCommand("SELECT JobNo, ProjNo FROM PT_Project")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = readProj.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            If JobNo = "" Or ProjNo = "" Or ProjName = "" Or ProjType = "" Then
                MsgBox("Project Number, Project Name, and Project Type are all required to be filled in.")
                txtAddJobNo.Focus()
                dr.Close()
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf JobNo = dr("JobNo") AndAlso ProjNo = dr("ProjNo") Then
                txtAddJobNo.Focus()
                MsgBox("The combination of Job and Project numbers you've entered already exists.")
                txtAddProjNo.Focus()
                dr.Close()
                Exit Sub
            Else
            End If
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

    'comfirm changes
    Dim Reply As String = ""

    Reply = MsgBox("I am ready to ADD Project?", vbYesNo)

    If Reply = vbYes Then
        Dim dbAdd As New SqlCommand("PT_AddManageProjects", frmMainMenu.DB)
        dbAdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SPUse", 3))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JobNo", JobNo))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjNo", ProjNo))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectName", ProjName))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectType", ProjType))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectTypeDescription", ProjTypeDesc))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectCost", ProjCost))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProjectBudgeted", ProjBudg))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Deleted", DBNull.Value))
        dbAdd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Active", DBNull.Value))
        dbAdd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Project has been added succesfully.")
        'clear the form after successful addition
        Call clearAddGroupbx()
    Else
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtAddProjNo_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAddProjNo.LostFocus

    Dim readProj As New SqlCommand("SELECT JobNo, ProjNo FROM PT_Project")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = readProj.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            If txtAddJobNo.Text = dr("JobNo") AndAlso txtAddProjNo.Text = dr("ProjNo") Then
                MsgBox("The combination of numbers you've entered already exists.")
                txtAddProjNo.Focus()
                dr.Close()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()

End Sub

Sub clearAddGroupbx()

    txtAddJobNo.Text = ""
    txtAddProjNo.Text = ""
    txtAddProjName.Text = ""
    cmbAddProjType.Text = ""
    txtAddProjTypeDesc.Text = ""
    txtAddProjCost.Text = ""
    txtAddProjBudget.Text = ""

End Sub

Sub clearEditGroupbx()

    cmbEditJobNo.Text = ""
    cmbEditProjNo.Text = ""
    txtEditRicc.Text = ""
    txtEditProjName.Text = ""
    cmbEditProjType.Text = ""
    txtEditProjTypeDesc.Text = ""
    txtEditProjCost.Text = ""
    txtEditProjBudget.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    Call clearAddGroupbx()
    Call clearEditGroupbx()

End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click

    Me.Close()
    Me.Dispose()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Nearly all NullReference Exceptions have the same set of causes.  See [NullReference Exception in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452) for help on this.  Where is this code located?  What is the exact line?

Comment: Please clarify: Is cmbEditProjType set to Nothing? Or is cmbEditProjType.Items set to Nothing?

Comment: Also, re: "i attempted to initialize it before adding the items to it, got the error; attempted to hard code one of the list items rather than pulling from the database, got the error." - show your initialization code, please.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the NullReferenceException however why do you need a List of distinct items that are already distinct? I am referring to values content

Comment: You don't even need For Each. Why not just cmbEditProjType.DataSource = result? Or directly cmbEditProjType.DataSource = values

Comment: PLUTONIX: The link you supplied was VERY informative, thank you!!  It did make a lot of sense, but I still can't seem to get to the root of my specific problem.  As you may have noticed, I updated my post to include the entirety of my code because just running the original snippet works fine, so it's obviously elsewhere that the problem lies.

Comment: RSKAR: 'cmbEditProjType' does not have anything assigned in it's collection... I am trying to fill it with the list I am creating in the code, THEN having the text show what the record is or the project in the database reader.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out what the problem was was that I had inadvertently set my `Generate Member` property to `false`.  After noticing this and changing it back to `true` i was able to simply populate the collection of the `dropdownlist` and use `.selectedtext` to show what was read from the data base. That would explain why none of the other questions posted were helping me. Feeling pretty silly now... apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codes:

```
Dim values As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
values.Add("Home")
values.Add("Office")
values.Add("Garage")
values.Add("Pool")
values.Add("Lawn")
values.Add("Maintain")
values.Add("Education")

'Filter distinct elements, and convert back into list
Dim result As List(Of String) = values.Distinct().ToList
'Display result
For Each element As String In result
    cmbEditProjType.Items.Add(element)
Next
```

And no any [NullReferenceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or another exceptions.

May be your exceptions is from `Dim dr As SqlDataReader = fillProjNo.ExecuteReader()` and it's not get any data from SQL !!!